# Framewok7 backbutton listener not working on multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, html-framework-7

I am attempting to prevent my `cordova` android application to NOT close when the physical back button is pressed on my mobile phone (android), instead, I want to open a dialog box to press the button twice before closing the application but I cannot figure it how to call or listen to the back button properly.

Here are my tabs using `framework7`

```
<div class="toolbar tabbar-labels toolbar-bottom-md">
        <div class="toolbar-inner">
          <a href="#view-home" class="tab-link tab-link-active">
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">home</i>
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">home_fill</i>
            <i class="icon material-icons md-only">home</i>
            <span class="tabbar-label">Home</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#view-catalog" class="tab-link">
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">list</i>
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">list_fill</i>
            <i class="icon material-icons md-only">view_list</i>
            <span class="tabbar-label">catalog</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#view-settings" class="tab-link">
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only">settings</i>
            <i class="icon f7-icons ios-only icon-ios-fill">settings_fill</i>
            <i class="icon material-icons md-only">settings</i>
            <span class="tabbar-label">Settings</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Framework7 initialization note that I already declared the `pushState`

```
 var app  = new Framework7({
      root: '#app',  
      id: 'io.HomeApplication.Homeapp',  
      name: 'My Application',  
      theme: 'auto',  
      pushState :true,   

 //other methods,data here
```

Initialize the views

```
// Init/Create views
var homeView = app.views.create('#view-home', {
  url: '/',
  on: {
    pageInit: function (e, page) {
      // do something when page initialized
      document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    } 
  }
});

 var catalogView = app.views.create('#view-catalog', {
    url: '/devices/'
  });

var settingsView = app.views.create('#view-settings', {
  url: '/settings/'
});
```

First, I was calling the `onBackKeyDown` as a function.

```
function onBackKeyDown(){

}
```

But now I placed it on my `app` method.

```
// App root methods
  methods: {

    onBackKeyDown: function(){

      app.dialog.alert('this was called');

    },
```

But still, when I press the backbutton on my mobile phone it doesn't execute any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your onBackKeyDown listener is inside `view-home` view.
Takes out from this and place it at same level of rest of your code :

```
 var app  = new Framework7({.....});
 document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

It should be makes your listener for all application.

Comment: Thanks for your response I try what you suggested by still no luck I also followed the documentation of cordova https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html the `onDeviceReady` is firing on a browser but on my android phone nothing happens putting an alert on backbutton.